# Security execution when trying to use pplus in Asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, epplus, securityexception

I'm trying to use EPPlus in Asp.net application And I'm getting this exception:

```
Attempt by security transparent method 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Init()' to access security critical method 'System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.get_Instance()' failed. 
System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Init()' to access security critical method 'System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.get_Instance()' failed. Assembly 'EPPlus, Version=5.7.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1' is marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency model. 
Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception. at 
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Init() at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage..ctor() at 
Utilities.Database.EPPlus.EPPlusHelpers.WriteToExcel(DataColumn[] columns, IEnumerable`1 data, Stream output, String worksheetName, ColumnFormatProvider formatProvider) at 
WebClient.Reports.ReportsPane2.<>c__DisplayClass60_0.b__0(String tempFilename) at
Utilities.WebUI.Utils.ReturnGeneratedFile(Boolean returnInResponse, String tempPath, String 
filename, String contentType, Encoding encoding, Action`1 fileGenerator) at
WebClient.Reports.ReportsPane2.ReportToExcel(Int32 controllerID, IEnumerable`1 dataPoints, Dictionary`2 displayInfo, Boolean displayDiscreteValues) at
WebClient.Reports.ReportsPane2.ReportDirectExport(ReportDefinition reportDef, ExportFormat exportFormat)
```

The Asp.net application is a .NET Framework 4.7.2 which references a .NET Standard 2.0 library protect which uses EPPlus 5.7.5 NuGet package.

I've tried adding

```
configuration>
    <system.web>
       <trust level="Full" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

to the `web.config`, but it did not work.

The previous version of the application used .NET Framework 4.6
with a .NET Framework library project which referenced EPPlus 4.5.1 NuGet package, that worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this problem by Changing the project that was using EPPlus
to use multi targeting netstandard2.0 & net472.
(luckily this project was used directly from the ASP.NET application)